# Tabulate normalized data in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827382/postgresql-how-to-combine-multiple-rows) question is similar to what I need to do, but the voted answer only partially solves the problem. Consider this table:

```
ID   |  TEST  |  RESULT
001  |  AAA   |  +
001  |  BBB   |  +
002  |  AAA   |  +
003  |  BBB   |  +
```

I would like output like this:

```
ID   |  AAA |  BBB
001  |  +   |  +
002  |  +   |  
003  |      |  +
```

The solution I mentioned above provides the same data as its output, but does not "skip over" the empty columns, as for `003`. Therefore, it is not possible to determine which test a `+` result refers to. I'm using PostgreSQL 8.4.9.

PS: Is a solution in pure SQL possible? Would this need to be coded in PL/pgSQL instead?

Comment: Does `TEST` column have exactly two values ?

Comment: Yes, `TEST` has a number of different values. I would just select the values I wanted to include with `WHERE`? The output I require at the moment only uses two of the possible `TEST` values, but ideally I would like to do this in future with a few columns -- maybe up to a dozen.

Comment: tablefunc (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/tablefunc.html) may be what I'm looking for.

Comment: yes... see my answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick and dirty solution you can use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
T.ID,
(SELECT A.RESULT FROM MyTable A WHERE A.TEST = 'AAA' AND A.ID = T.ID) AS AAA,
(SELECT B.RESULT FROM MyTable B WHERE B.TEST = 'BBB' AND B.ID = T.ID) AS BBB
FROM MyTable T;
```

If you need that more dynamic consider using [`crosstab`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/tablefunc.html) function in the `SELECT`.

Comment: The single quotations around `AAA` and `BBB` after `AS` should be removed (at least for the query to work for me). Thanks -- that query works perfectly. It takes quite a long time to run extracting two test results (26 seconds on a table of 6000 rows), but this isn't a problem at the moment -- I'm just glad to get the output I need.

Comment: @SabreWolfy changed it... glad this was of help :-)

Comment: Thanks :) If I want to return more than one column (for example A.RESULT and A.DATE) I should look at `crosstab`?

Comment: @SabreWolfy not sure that crosstab can do that although I would check it out anyway since it can gain you a bit more performance...