# sql return json object by status from two tables with different number of rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, pivot, inner-join

I am using PostgreSQL 9.5

I have two table:

A

```
ID | isStatusA | IsStatusB | IsStatusC
0  | true      | false     | true
```

A table has only 1 row for data I need. Also i have B table with:

```
ID | status | a_id
0  | A      | 0
0  | C      | 0
```

When I wrote my select with "from A inner join B on a.id = b.a_id" that I got 2 rows. I have to get only one row (or json object) with checking that is that true/false in table A and is status present in table B. To return true i have to check both conditions.

Expected output: `{A: true, B: false, C:true}`

Comment: Please share expected output.

Comment: @Pankaj I want {A: true, B: false, C:true} or something similar with using pivot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PostgreSQL [`ARRAY_AGG()`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-aggregate-functions/postgresql-array_agg/) function along with [`GROUP BY`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-group-by/) to "denormalize" the `B` table `status` column. Then [`INNER JOIN`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-inner-join/) table `A` with an ad hoc, temporary table, here named `B_agg`.

```
SELECT A.*, B_agg.status_agg
  FROM A
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT a_id, ARRAY_AGG(status) status_agg FROM B GROUP BY a_id
    ) B_agg ON A.ID = B_agg.a_id
;
```

Output:

| id | isstatusa | isstatusb | isstatusc | status_agg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | t | t | f | {A,C} |

The temporary table query:

```
SELECT a_id, ARRAY_AGG(status) status_agg FROM B GROUP BY a_id
```

...outputs:

| a_id | status_agg |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | {A,C} |

This result is then is [`INNER JOIN`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-inner-join/)'ed with table `A` connecting columns `A.ID` and `B_agg.a_id`: `ON A.ID = B_agg.a_id`.

The temporary table is given the alias `B_agg` for access outside the temporary table query, such as: `B_agg.status_agg`.

Try it here: https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3yfyffrrg

Credit to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6558226/2743458

Comment: Thank you. That's something similar that i expected, but not the same. I getting {A,B,C} as result from "B_agg.status_agg". I wanted {A: true, B: false, C:true} or something similar with using pivot

Comment: Ok. I fixed it on my own. For future devs with same problem :
I select now CASE WHEN A.isStatusA = true and 'A' = ANY (B_agg.status_agg) THEN true else false. Same with B but with changed letter. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

Using [`JSON_AGG()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.27.5.2.4.12.1.1.1) and [`JSON_BUILD_OBJECT()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.5.9.2.2.5.1.1.1) to create a JSON object and assign desired object key names:

```
SELECT JSON_AGG(
  JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('A',isStatusA,'B',isStatusB,'C',isStatusB)
) status_agg
  FROM A
;
```

Output:

| status_agg |
| --- |
| [{"A" : true, "B" : true, "C" : true}] |

Try it here: https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3yfyjt24r

The `A` table provides all the information necessary to produce the output `{A: true, B: false, C:true}`.

Can also including the `ID` column in case multiple IDs are collected in a single query:

```
SELECT JSON_AGG(
  JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(ID,
    JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('A',isStatusA,'B',isStatusB,'C',isStatusB)
  )
) status_agg
  FROM A
;
```

Output:

| status_agg |
| --- |
| [{"0" : {"A" : true, "B" : true, "C" : true}}] |

Comment: I have to check in both tables. Your comment was my first version and later i got information that i have to check also in table B. problem already solved i think :)